# Writing Regex for phonenumber

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex to match phone numbers in following format i.e.

1- without country code
9999999999

2 - with 1 digit country code
+19999999999

3 - with country code and ()
+1(999)9999999

4 - with country code () and -
+1(999)-999-9999

I wrote a regex which matches condition 2 but failed in 1,3 and 4.

```
^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$
```

As soon as I adds country code after + sign along with () and - my regex stops working.

How Can I fix it? I am not a regex pro and assembled my regex by trying different patterns that I got by googling.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI please !! This attached dupe is very generic duplicate, this current question is a specific one; and none of the answers given in dupe are meeting this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has added sample of phone numbers to be matched with + sign so adding following answer now.

```
^(?:\d{10})?(?:\+)?(?:(?:\d{11})?(?:\d\(\d{3}\))?(?:(?:\d{7})?(?:-\d{3}-\d{4})?))$
```

[Here is Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/9t7q7m/1)

---

---

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
^\+(?:(?:\d{11})?(?:\d\(\d{3}\))?(?:(?:\d{7})?(?:-\d{3}-\d{4})?))$
```

[Here is Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/G9hbbP/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^\+                        ##Checking if starting is from + sign.
(?:                        ##Starting a non-capturing group from here.
   (?:\d{11})?             ##Starting a non-capturing group which matches 11 digits here, keeping it optional.
   (?:\d\(\d{3}\))?        ##Starting a non-capturing group which matches single digit followed by ( 3 digits followed by ) and keeping this optional too.
   (?:                     ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
     (?:\d{7})?            ##Starting a non-capturing group here with 7 digits keeping it optional.
     (?:-\d{3}-\d{4})?     ##Starting a non-capturing group which has - 3 digits - 4 digits keep it optional.
   )                       ##Closing above non-capturing group here.
)$                         ##Closing very first non-capturing group here.
```

Comment: it works but It failed to match normal 10 digit number like 9999999999

Comment: @SiddheshDilipKumar, ok you mean without starting `+`? Sorry but I believe that sample was not given in your question, please confirm if you want to match numbers without + here, thank you.

Comment: @SiddheshDilipKumar, ok sure, please try `^(?:\d{10})?(?:\+)?(?:(?:\d{11})?(?:\d\(\d{3}\))?(?:(?:\d{7})?(?:-\d{3}-\d{4})?))$` once and let me know if this helps you? Once you confirm here, I will update the answer then.

Comment: I have one doubt though. what if country code is two digits then how can i edit (?:\d{11}). if I wrote (?:\d{1, })then it will accept two digit country code but looks bad.

Comment: @SiddheshDilipKumar, ok nice try :) could country code be more than 2 digits also?(sorry I am not sure on it)

Comment: @SiddheshDilipKumar, if country code is between 1 to 2 digits then try following, `^(?:\d{10})?(?:\+)?(?:(?:\d{11})?(?:\d{1,3}\(\d{3}\))?(?:(?:\d{7})?(?:-\d{3}-\d{4})?))$` once.

Comment: I am not sure about that but in most common cases country codes can be 1 to  3 digits. Even in some cases it can be 1-868 ( Trinidad and Tobago )

Comment: @SiddheshDilipKumar, oh ok sure, I have edited my previous comment's code, please do check it once and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my two cents to your question. It looks like the following ticks the boxes too:

```
^(?:\+\d(?:\(\d{3}\)(?:-\d{3}-|\d{3})|\d{6})|\d{6})\d{4}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2jNGo4/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group:

  - `\+\d` - A literal "+" and a single digit.
  - `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group:

    - `\(\d{3}\)` - Match three digits between opening and closing paranthesis.
    - `(?:` - Open 3rd non-capture group:

      - `-\d{3}-` - Three digits between dashes.
      - `|` - Or:
      - `\d{3})` - Just three digits before closing 3rd non-capture group.
    - `|` - Or:
    - `\d{6})` - Just six digits before closing 2nd non-capture group.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `\d{6})` - Or just six digits before closing 1st non-capture group.
- `\d{4}` - Four digits.
- `$` - End line anchor.

Add an optional digit to the pattern to allow for 2-digit countrycodes too, e.g:

```
^(?:\+\d\d?(?:\(\d{3}\)(?:-\d{3}-|\d{3})|\d{6})|\d{6})\d{4}$
```

Comment: thanks @JvdV Your explanations helped me to understand little bit more about regex.